# Voltage Gain decreases when load resistance included

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Why does the voltage gain of a  (voltage divider) common emitter bypassed emitter bias bjt amplifier decreases when putting a load resistance on the output Vo? 
I mean Vo should remain the same because resistances in parallel have the same voltage across them.
Link below provides the image for the circuit diagram:

https://www.google.mu/search?q=voltage+divider+bias+bjt+amplifier&newwindow=1&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIksf_me-UyAIVRlwaCh3x6w9j&biw=1366&bih=667#imgrc=ZAlOvfkzwcITRM%3A

Answer (score 1):

The voltage gain is just the transconductance gm multiplied by the collector resistance in parallel with Va/Ic = ro (the latter accounting for the Early voltage). See the [hybrid pi model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model), which is the minimum model you need to predict the voltage gain.

Any load resistance appears in parallel with the collector resistance, so the voltage gain drops proportionally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the picture: -

[image]

Output voltage is \$I_C R_L\$ and, if \$R_L\$ halves then voltage gain halves. I believe you are mistakingly thinking that the collector generates a voltage. It doesn't. A BJT is commonly defined as having current gain i.e. Ic/Ib (or hFE). Input current is proportional to input voltage in the circuit above so now you have the transistor with an output current for a given input voltage.

The output current is converted to a voltage by \$R_L\$ and of course, the lower the value of RL, the lower the output voltage for a given input signal.